# How to call 3 or 4 callback functions

Tags: javascript

I need to understand how callback functions works.
I wrote this little script with 2 functions :

```
function fn1(callback) {
  alert('fn1');
  callback();
}

function fn2() {
  alert('fn2');
}

fn1(fn2); //display 'fn1' then 'fn2'
```

Now, I want to update my script with a "fn3" function in order to display 'fn1' then 'fn2' then 'fn3'. I tried this :

```
function fn1(callback) {
  alert('fn1');
  callback();
}

function fn2(callback) {
  alert('fn2');
  callback();
}

function fn3() {
  alert('fn3');
}

fn1(fn2(fn3));
```

but it dispay 'fn2', then 'fn3', then 'fn1', then log an error ("*callback is not a function*").
Any idea ? what's wrong ?
Thanks in advance, Florent.

Comment: Trouble is that `fn2(fn3)` _executes_ fn2, and then f1 receives the _result_ of that function as its parameter, not the function reference itself.

Comment: What is the idea here? Should fn2 always know that it has to call fn3, or do you wish to specify the order of the callbacks each time, and have them execute in a dynamically defined sequence? I only ask because, if it's the latter, there's really no need for any callbacks at all, you can just execute the functions in order. The only reason to do it this way would be if some/all of them in real life will be async and you need to wait until they're done before continuing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to execute `f1` then `f2` then `f3` you need to create a callback function in order to make sure a function will be executed in steps.

wrong:

```
fn1(fn2(fn3))) // this first call f2 with f3 as parameter then calls f1 with its result
```

right:

```
fn1(function () { // call f1
  fn2(function () { // then call f2 after f1
    fn3(); // then call f3 after f2
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

> `fn3`

You take the value `fn3` which is a function.

> `fn2(fn3)`

You pass that value as the argument to `fn2`, another function, which you call.

> `function fn2(callback) { alert('fn2'); callback(); }`

You alert, then you call the argument (the function you got from `fn3`) as a function (I'll skip over the details of what it does) and then return `undefined` (since you have no return statement).

> `fn1(fn2(fn3));`

Since `fn2(fn3)` returns `undefined` this is the same as `fn1(undefined)`.

> `function fn1(callback) { alert('fn1'); callback(); }`

You alert, then try to call `undefined` as a function, which it isn't, so it errors.

---

> How to call 3 or 4 callback functions

Probably… rewrite the functions so they make use of [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) instead of plain old callbacks.

But there is no point in using callbacks for your example at all, and the best solution to a real problem will depend on what that problem is.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds more like you're looking for [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```js
function fn1(){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      alert("fn1");
      resolve()
    });
}

function fn2(){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      alert("fn2");
      resolve()
    });
}

function fn3(){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      alert("fn3");
      resolve()
    });
}

fn1().then(fn2).then(fn3);
```

Answer (score 0):

fn1(fn2(fn3))

Here we have a call to function `fn1` with 1 argument which is return value of function `fn2`. This statement is evaluated so that `fn2` is first called with its parameter `fn3` and then the return value is passed to `fn1`. `fn2` calls its parameter. This is why you get "unexpected" order of alerts.

`fn2` does not return anything so that is why you get error from `fn1`.